# How to Keep a Div 20 PX Away from all Edges

Tags: html, css

I have a site I am building and I'd like the content to be in a div with a border, and I'd like that div's border to be 20 px away from all edges no matter what is going on with the sizing of the window.  I have been trying to use right: left: right-margin: and left-margin: with little success.  Here is the css code as it currently is:

```
#content_div {
border-radius: 15px;
border: 2px solid #E07A1A;
padding: 20px;
color: LightGray;
font-family: var(--global-font-family);
font-size: 1.5rem;

position: absolute;
top: 130px;
left: 20px;
right: -20px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 90%;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The top border is behaving because I hard coded the position for it at 130 px, which honestly, I am fine with.  The left: attribute seems to be working at keeping the border 20 px away from the left edge of the browser.  The right: not so much.

The bottom just disappears off the page (actually I gave up trying to get it to work and removed bottom: and margin-bottom from the code for now).

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

In response to the comment below, having just top, bottom, right, and left and nothing else results in the left and right being glues to the browser's edge, and the bottom glued to the bottom of the text, like so:

[image]

Comment: `top:120px;right:20px;left:20px;bottom:20px` and remove everything else (margin, width, height)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your solution does not work, tho.  The right and left are glues to the browser edge and the bottom follows the text, not the browser window.  I'll post a pic a above to illustrate,

Comment: share a working code, not screenshot. My solution does work but you have probably more CSS involved

Comment: I am sure you are right!  I'll post the code when I get home tonight...